# I'm stuck trying to reverse this formula

Tags: c++, reverse-engineering, bit-shift

I'm trying to reverse engineer a game function, which takes an integer and returns a 64-bit integer, by writing a function which returns the original value before it was put through the game function. How do I achieve this?

I have only managed to reverse these steps:

```
x = ((1 - x) << 16)
```

I'm not sure how to reverse the addition without the original value.

Here is the game function:

```
int64_t convert(int x) {
  if (x <= 0)
    return (1 - ((((x + 1) >> 31) + x + 1) >> 16));
  else
    return 0;
}
```

For example, if the original value was -5175633 then the converted value would be 80, I need to get the original value from 80.

Comment: what is the value for sizeof(int) ?

Comment: Use SMT solver like Z3 to solve such problems.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think this is possible. When you right-shift an integer, bits are lost. This means there are multiple input values that would return the same output value.

Sorry Victor, but your solution doesn't work. You ought to be comparing r and i, not c and cc.

Comment: You are right. My solution is only to give a value that has the same output. As I have pointed out: convert(-5177344) will give 80 the same as convert(-5175633) so you can not decide between them.

Answer (score 1):

Let's assume, with the step `(1 - ((((x + 1) >> 31) + x + 1) >> 16))`, `x` has converted to `y`, the we get:

```
y = 1 - ((((x + 1) >> 31) + x + 1) >> 16)
1 - y = (((x + 1) >> 31) + x + 1) >> 16
(1 - y) << 16 = (x + 1) >> 31 + x + 1
```

If `x` <= 0, then `x + 1` <= 1. However this can't decide the sign bit. So we should assume once more.

if `x + 1` < 0, then `(x + 1) >> 31` is -1, which `x` < -1, `y` which is `1 - ((((x + 1) >> 31) + x + 1) >> 16)`, is `1 - (x >> 16)`

```
(1 - y) << 16 = -1 + x + 1
(1 - y) << 16 = x
```

if `x + 1` >= 0, then `(x + 1) >> 31` is 0, which `x` >= -1, and `y`, which is `1 - ((((x + 1) >> 31) + x + 1) >> 16)`, is 1. (*Note: now x can only be 0 or -1*)

```
(1 - y) << 16 = x + 1
(1 - y) << 16 - 1 = x
```

So, include these two results together, we can get:

```
int reverse_convert(int64_t y) {
    if (y == 1)
        return (1 - y) << 16 - 1; // However, either x = 0 or x = 1 can produce this result.
    else
        return (1 - y) << 16;
    // the condition of y == 0, corresponding to the original "else return 0;", is ignored.
}
```

Besides, the `convert` function is a [Surjective-only](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bijection,_injection_and_surjection) function, which means multiple input can get the same output, then it is impossible to reverse *precise* output into input.

Answer (score 0):

I will assume sizeof(int) is 4. And all the operations are done on 32 bits.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int64_t convert(int32_t x) {
  if (x <= 0)
    return (1 - ((((x + 1) >> 31) + x + 1) >> 16));
  else
    return 0;
}

int32_t revconvert(int64_t r) {
    if (r == 0) return 0;
    if (r == 1) return -1;
    return (1-r) << 16;
}

int main()
{
    int32_t i;
    for (i=0;i>-10000000;--i) {
        auto c = convert(i);
        auto r = revconvert(c);
        auto cc = convert(r);
        if( c!=cc) break;
    }

    cout << i << endl; // just to see if we got to the end

    cout << convert(-5175633) << endl; // Will give 80
    cout << revconvert(80) << endl; // Will give -5177344
    cout << convert(-5177344) << endl; // Will give 80

    return 0;
}
```